# File disappeared from NTFS after Ubuntu installation

Tags: installation, ntfs, data-recovery

I wanted to upgrade a very old version of Ubuntu to a recent one, so I made the following steps:

1. I created a large (over 30GB) tar.gz archive containing all data from my home directory
2. Moved it to NTFS partition
3. Launched Ubuntu 12.04 from CD
4. Resized the NTFS partition during installation
5. Completed the installation

Then I launched my brand new Ubuntu and wanted to copy the archive so:

1. I mounted the partition on which the archive was located
2. I have run `ls -l` in the place of file size, modification date etc., a `?` appeared instead of any values
3. I launched Windows XP which is installed on the same machine and it did not show that file on the partition at all
4. Linux also does not show the file anymore

I tried running `chkdsk` under Windows which did not fix the problem. I also tried `ntfsundelete` in Linux which shows that this file cannot be recovered.

I would appreciate any help very much! I have lost a lot of data. What could have happened? Is there any chance of recovering this file?

Answer (score 2):

Two things could have happened.

1)The resize/shrink had some bug that caused the file to get "lost" (possible, but not horribly likely)

2)The partition was forcibly unmounted before cached disk writes were flushed (a lot more likely with a 30GB write to an external drive, even moreso if you piped tar or something to that effect)

In the prior case, recovery *may* be possible with FTK, foremost, scalpel, or some other tool.  In the latter case, complete recovery is a LOT less likely.

Either way, complete recovery is less than likely.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with human error - is there a chance that you didn't uncheck "format" checkbox for this ntfs partition?

Comment: No, that is not possible - all other files on the partition remained untouched.